# Feed function with result of another function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, signature

I have a function that select ID of some interesting rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ChannelSelection(...)
RETURNS TABLE(
    ChannelId INTEGER
) AS [...]
```

It takes some arguments for filtering purpose and return a `SETOF INTEGER`.

I would like to use the result of this function `ChannelSelection` to feed another one, which accept `INTEGER[]` as input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DataP2AMean(
      _channelid INTEGER[] = NULL
)
    RETURNS TABLE(
        ChannelId INTEGER,
        ...
    )  AS
$BODY$
SELECT
    D2.ChannelId,
    ...
FROM
    ...
WHERE
    D2.ChannelId = ANY(_channelid)
    OR _channelid IS NULL

$BODY$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

When I issue the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM DataP2AMean(_channelid := ChannelSelection(_site := '{41WOL1,41N043}'))
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Function datap2amean(integer) doesn't exist
State SQL :42883 (undefined_function)
```

Which I do not understand because I am able to use those functions separately. It looks like it search for another signature, thus that `ChannelSelection` returns only one integer, but it is not the case.

What am I missing?

Comment: I know now that it is a signature problem, but I do not find how to make INTEGER[] and SETOF INTEGER match. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`channelselection` returns a **table** (=set) of integers. So potentially many, many rows with a single integer column. datap2amean expects a **single** (array) value, not a set of integer values.

Unfortunately using e.g.

```
select array_agg(i) from channelselection('{41WOL1,41N043}') i
```

would still not help, because that also returns a *set* of integer arrays. We *know* that it will only ever return a single row - but a single row with one array column is still something different than a single integer array value.

So you would need to cast the result into a single value, e.g. like this:

```
(select array_agg(i) from channelselection('{41WOL1,41N043}') i)::int[]
```

This can then be used as a parameter to the other function:

```
SELECT *
FROM datap2amean ( (select array_agg(i) from channelselection('{41WOL1,41N043}') i)::int[] )
```

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM airpy.DataP2AMean(_channelid := array(SELECT * FROM airpy.ChannelSelection(_site := '{41WOL1,41N043}')))` also works, I just found it. Thanks for your answer anyway